# Selectively Disabling PHP via .htaccess in Root Directory

Tags: htaccess, security

I'm reading up on securing WordPress and one of the commonly suggested techniques is to use an .htaccess file to disallow PHP execution in `wp-content` and `wp-includes`. I then read about [another hack](http://blog.sucuri.net/2013/07/dissecting-a-wordpress-brute-force-attack.html) that involved a backdoor file placed in the root directory. That got me thinking about how to extend the technique. Would it make sense to do something like this:

In root directory .htaccess:

```
<Files *.php>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
</Files>

<Files index.php>
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
</Files>
```

In wp-admin .htaccess:

```
<Files *.php>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Allow from all
</Files>
```

I'm pretty sure this will break XML-RPC support as well as post by email, but I don't plan on using either of those technologies anyway. I'm wondering if there are other consequences that I'm not seeing (I don't know 100% what all of the PHP files in the root directory are for). Is this even worth it?

Comment: That would make no sense whatsoever.

Comment: @Wyck, thanks for the input. Could you maybe explain why it wouldn't make any sense?

Comment: It just doesn't, it's like securing your house by bricking it over, no one does that for a reason.

Answer (score 1):

No, it will not work.

You pretty much will disable php to work on your site admin.

On `wp-admin` there are files being executed when entering the admin side of the site.

Comment: Won't the `allow from all` directive in the wp-admin .htaccess allow the admin area to work?

Comment: Why would you add that .htaccess at all?
It doesnt make any sense to use it in the first place.
(You are adding an .htaccess to do ... nothing)

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but as I understand it, the root dir .htaccess will disallow direct access to any PHP file except index.php. This will cascade into subdirectories, so you override it with the .htaccess in `wp-admin` to allow the admin panel to work normally. It's basically an extension of the practices described [here](http://blog.sucuri.net/2012/08/wordpress-security-cutting-through-the-bs.html) and [here](http://blog.sucuri.net/2012/07/wordpress-and-server-hardening-taking-security-to-another-level.html).